# Unsupported media type when uploading form data to spring server

Tags: node.js, spring, http, express, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file to a remote spring server via an API, and I keep getting an unsupported media type error (415) even though I have already made the data into form data.

Here is the express http post request:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var form = new FormData();

form.append('pid', params.pid);
form.append('deliveryAttachment', fs.createReadStream(params.deliveryAttachment.path));

var url = someDomain + '/proj/new/deliveryAttachment';
requestLib({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    jar: getJar(),
    form: form
},function (error, response, body){     
    console.log(body)
});
```

And here is the Java Spring controller for reference:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "proj/new/deliveryAttachment", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String insertDeliveryAttachment(@RequestParam("pid") long pid,
        @RequestParam("deliveryAttachment") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        DeliveryAttachment a = new DeliveryAttachment(file.getOriginalFilename(), pid);
        ps.insertDeliveryAttachment(a, file.getBytes());
        return String.valueOf(a.id);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "-1";
    }
}
```

This is the form data console log:

[image]

And the 415 response:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1494671395688,
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
  "message": "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported",
  "path": "/proj/new/deliveryAttachment"
}
```

**--UPDATE--**

Alright, I just found out after reading request's docs that if you use `form` as the holder for the data, it will treat the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

e.g.; `request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ ... });`

Meanwhile the correct key for `multipart/form-data` is `formData`

e.g.;  `request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) { ... });`

I tried it, and now it's giving me a new error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null at FormData._getContentDisposition`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are sending a POST request with `Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, and your SpringController `insertDeliveryAttachment()` consumes `multipart/form-data` mime-type.

I would recommend you to change the consumes mime-type on your `insertDeliveryAttachment()` method to `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE`

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. What if for example I have no way of changing the `insertDeliveryAttachment()` method? Is it possible to have the workaround in the request in express?

Comment: Yes, then you must send your request with `multipart/form-data`. You can use [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to achieve this.

Please check this [link](http://derpturkey.com/node-multipart-form-data-explained/) for detailed information about `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I just looked at it, and it seems that I am already sending `multipart/form-data`. But for some reason, the server thinks I am sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. I did not use FormData and just went with inserting the values inside an object and it worked.

```
var data = {
    pid: params.pid,
    deliveryAttachment: fs.createReadStream(params.deliveryAttachment[0].path)
};  

var url = wfDomain + '/proj/new/deliveryAttachment';
requestLib({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },  
    jar: getJar(),
    formData: data
},function (error, response, body){ ... });
```